# Why does ivreg function generate strange error

Tags: r, ivreg

I'm trying to use instrument variables for the following three variables: pwtopen, inc, incsqr with the following three instruments:  elhsfs, incf, incfsqr.  polity is an exegenous variable.

```
    answer<- ivreg(sulfdm ~ polity + pwtopen + inc + incsqr|polity + elhsfs + incf + incfsqr, 
    mydata)
```

I am then getting the error message:
Error in ivreg(sulfdm ~ polity + pwtopen + inc + incsqr | polity + elhsfs +  : 
  length(formula)[1] == 1L is not TRUE

Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use the arguments in this case:

ivreg(formula, instruments, data, subset, na.action, weights, offset,
contrasts = NULL, model = TRUE, y = TRUE, x = FALSE, …)

As you didn't specify the arguments, the function tried to use your data as "instrument".

So, this should solve your problem:

```
answer<- ivreg(sulfdm ~ polity + pwtopen + inc + incsqr|polity + elhsfs + incf + incfsqr, 
data = mydata)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Rewriting the command as below solved it:

```
 answer <- ivreg(sulfdm ~ polity + pwtopen + inc + incsqr, ~polity + elhsfs + incf + incfsqr, mydata)
```